# Condição Matrizes python

Tags: python

Meu Código:

```
 m1 = [[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]]
 m2 = [[2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7]]

def soma_matrizes(m1, m2):
       matriz_soma = []
       linhas = len(m1) 
       colunas = len(m1[0]) 
  for i in range(linhas):
       matriz_soma.append([])
       for j in range(colunas):
            soma = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j]
            matriz_soma[i].append(soma)
 return matriz_soma
```

Exemplo 1:

```
 m1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
 m2 = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
 soma_matrizes(m1, m2) => [[3, 5, 7], [9, 11, 13]]
```

Exemplo 2:

```
m1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
m2 = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
soma_matrizes(m1, m2) => False
```

O que eu tenho que fazer para que meu código atenda as exigências do exemplo1 e exemplo2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jeito mais simples é usar o [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), pois aí você pode comparar se o formato (`shape`) das matrizes é diferente, e se for retornar `False` como deseja. Exemplo de código:

```
def soma_matrizes(m1, m2):
    import numpy as np
    m1 = np.array(m1)
    m2 = np.array(m2)
    if m1.shape != m2.shape:
        return False
    else:
        return (m1 + m2).tolist()

m1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
m2 = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7]]  
print(soma_matrizes(m1, m2))

m1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
m2 = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7]]  
print(soma_matrizes(m1, m2))
```

Resultado:

```
[[3, 5, 7], [9, 11, 13]]
False
```

Veja funcionando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/ykSKBm).

### Edição:

Para fazer manualmente (considerando somente listas):

```
def sameShape(m1, m2):
    '''Verificação manual se duas listas têm o mesmo formato'''

    if type(m1) != type(m2):
        return False

    if type(m1) == list:
        if len(m1) != len(m2):
            return False

        for i in range(len(m1)):
            if not sameShape(m1[i], m2[i]):
                return False

    return True
```

Nesse caso, remova o uso da biblioteca Numpy e troque a linha:

```
if m1.shape != m2.shape:
```

por:

```
if not sameShape(m1, m2):
```

Porém, note que você *não pode mais* simplesmente fazer `m1 + m2`, pois esse operador concatena as listas do Python e não soma. Você pode usar o seu método de soma mesmo, ou então fazer assim (veja [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/A9Aoon)):

```
def sameShape(m1, m2):
    '''Verificação manual se duas listas têm o mesmo formato'''

    if type(m1) != type(m2):
        return False

    if type(m1) == list:
        if len(m1) != len(m2):
            return False

        for i in range(len(m1)):
            if not sameShape(m1[i], m2[i]):
                return False

    return True

def soma_matrizes(m1, m2):
    if not sameShape(m1, m2):
        return False
    else:
        # Reduz a dimensão da matriz de 2 pra 1 (i.e. transforma em lista simples)
        # para facilitar a soma
        m1 = [i for j in m1 for i in j]
        m2 = [i for j in m2 for i in j]

        # Calcula a soma item a item das duas listas
        s = [sum(t) for t in zip(m1, m2)] # <= usa `sum` em cada tupla
        #s = [i + j for i, j in zip(m1, m2)] # <== alternativa (talvez mais fácil de entender)

        # Faz a lista de soma ter 2 dimensões antes de retornar
        k = int(len(s) / 2)
        return [s[:k], s[k:]]

m1 = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
m2 = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7]]
print(soma_matrizes(m1, m2))

m1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
m2 = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7]]
print(soma_matrizes(m1, m2))
```

Enfim, observe que:

1. Esse código é muito maior e mais difícil de entender do que o anterior, com o Numpy.
2. Ele é específico para uma matriz com 2 dimensões e precisaria ser adaptado se a sua matriz tivesse mais dimensões. O código do Numpy já é de uso geral.

> Logo, eu discordo [do seu entendimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186570/condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-matrizes-python/186575?noredirect=1#comment386007_186575) de que sem o uso do pacote
>   é melhor (mesmo pra vc). :) Não é tão difícil de instalá-lo e vale
>   muito a pena! Pode acreditar.

Comment: uma solução sem modulo , caberia melhor

Comment: Se por "módulo" vc quer dizer sem usar o *pacote* Numpy, eu discordo de que caberia melhor. É muito mais fácil e prático assim (além de funcionar para qualquer quantidade de dimensões da matriz), e esse pacote é usado pra muitas outras coisas e é bem fácil de instalar (instala com o pip mesmo). De todas as formas, você não especificou na sua pergunta que não era pra usar um pacote, então eu considero que a resposta continua válida.

Comment: Agora, se vc quer fazer manualmente, é só comparar em cada dimensão se o tipo (use [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)) é o mesmo e se o tamanho (caso seja uma lista) é o mesmo (use [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)). O laço para verificar é o mesmo que vc já faz para somar.

Comment: caberia melhor a mim no caso ,porque não tenho modulo instalado ainda, mas obrigado Luiz

Comment: Editei pra adicionar uma sugestão de como fazer manualmente.

Comment: Olá Luiz, ontem já dei o meu +1 ontem de madrugada (tinha bebido uns copos e foi a unica coisa que consegui fazer), sem duvida que é melhor assim para coisas sérias. Quis no entanto entreter-me hoje com isto: http://ideone.com/2dnmKc

Comment: @Miguel Também estás curtindo o Carnaval por aí, então, não é? :) hehehe Muito boa a sua solução. Poste-a também como resposta. Serve como base de comparação pro AP e pra leitores futuros.

Comment: @LuizVieira se quiser acrescente-a na sua resposta assim ficam as duas juntas. Não foi por ser carnaval, foi por sexta feira lol :p

Comment: @Miguel Eu acho que se for para adicionar faz mais sentido ser outra resposta. Mesmo assim, obrigado! :)

Comment: Luiz não tenho nada para fazer, decidi ficar uma hora nisto agora lol: http://ideone.com/b5zNbr . Para número indefinido de listas